# f is separable iff gcd(f, f') = 1

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field. Let $f\in F[x]$. Then, $f$ is separable iff $\gcd(f, f') = 1$, where $f'$ is the formal derivative.

I'm slightly skeptical about the statement and would like some clarification. I fully buy that this is true in fields of char $0$, but say that $F$ has char $p>0$. Let $f\in F[x]$ be a polynomial (seperable or not) satisfying $\deg(f) = p$.

Then, $f' = 0$ and therefore $\gcd(f, f') = f$. Does this then mean that every polynomial of degree $k\cdot p$ (for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$) is inseparable? This cannot be the case (I think) since all finite fields are perfect and therefore all polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_p$ are separable.

Comment: If $\deg(f)=p$ then the top term disappears in $f'$ but there may still be other terms.

Comment: @EricWofsey Ohh, I see. How about polynomials of the form $x^p - c$ for some $c\in F$?

Comment: Those are indeed inseparable.  If $a$ is a $p$th root of $c$ (in some extension field), then $x^p-c$ factors as $(x-a)^p$.

Comment: @Obamafish: If $\text{char}(F)=p$ and $f=x^p+x$, what is $f'$?